# List active shortcuts in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In Eclipse it is possible to show the active shortcuts with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

List of shortcuts (depending on the context):

[image]

Is there something similar in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the best solution for me was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Then just type the desired action and you will see the shortcut or you can execute the action.

Example (call hierarchy):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such feature in IntelliJ IDEA. It could be implemented as a plugin, but as far as I'm aware such a plugin does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You may install this intellij plugin :

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=2391

Comment: Thx, I will try it :)

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+K which is used by the plugin conflicts with the GIT plugin and I do not find how to override it. Otherwise looks nice. Still someone complains, that it shows only the default settings and not the actual settings. It would be also good to have a text search inside the list. So mixed bag, but it is still the best option so far.